# Generating series numbers with adding String at middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

Am writing JavaScript plugin to one of my client, in this i need to generate a series strings like "1,2,D,3,4" / "1,D,2,3,4,5,6". length can be n numbers. "D" positions are stored in a separate string like 2,4. Here, based upon this length we want to generate like below

String = 1,2,3,4,5 D Positions: 2,4
Final result should be: 1,D,2,D,3

Something i tried,

```
 var deletedString = "2,4"
    var Values = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
    var lengthFromValues = SplitString_ToArray(Values).length;
    var deletedArray = splitString_ToArray(deletedString);
    var temp_arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= lengthFromValues; i++) {        
        if(deletedArray[i-1] > 0) {
          temp_arr.push("D");
        } else temp_arr.push(i);
    }
alert(temp_arr.toString());
```

Note: SplitString_ToArray function is a self written function which will convert(split) string to array.

Will someone help me?

Comment: Can you explain this example that you gave? "String = 1,2,3,4,5 D Positions: 2,4 Final result should be: 1,D,2,D,3" How?

Comment: Yes, you will have series string with n numbers like 1,2,3,4,5. I want to replace string "D" with some positions (assumed positions may be 3,4). once replaced, final string should be like this 1,2,D,D,3. String should be replaced and remaining numbers till nth value should be series aligned like mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var deletedString = "2,4"; /* Sort the values */
var Values = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

var allValues = Values.split(','),
    length = allValues.length;

deletedString.split(',').forEach(function(position) {
    allValues.splice(parseInt(position) - 1, 0, 'D');
});

var newValues = allValues.splice(0, length).join();
alert(newValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this I've changed a logic a bit. Actually you can use `deletedString` values to replace values in `Values` that you convert to array and then you just put the array back to string. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9M32w/1/)

```
var deletedString = "2,4"
var Values = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var deletedArray = SplitString_ToArray(deletedString);
var valuesArray = SplitString_ToArray(Values);
var finalLength = valuesArray.length;

for (i=0; i< deletedArray.length; i++){
    console.log(deletedArray[i]);
    var idxToReplace = parseInt(deletedArray[i]-1); // substract 1, because your indexes are 1-based
    valuesArray.splice(idxToReplace,0,'D');
}

// back to string
valuesArray = valuesArray.slice(0, finalLength);
var result = valuesArray.join();
alert(result);

function SplitString_ToArray(inString){
    var result = inString.split(',');
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i need the output as 1,D,2,D,3,4 [not 1,D,3,D,5,6].

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see you have to shift values as well; fixing will be provided shortly :)

Comment: Check it out, I hope that's it and that it is understandable.

Comment: Hi Berserker, logically error is there in the code, on applying positions, check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9M32w/3/

Answer (score 0):

Using a forEach loop this should do it:

```
var deletedString = "2,4";
var Values = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

var toDelete = deletedString.split(','),
    allValues = Values.split(','),
    length = allValues.length;

toDelete.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});

toDelete.forEach(function(position) {
    allValues.splice(parseInt(position) - 1, 0, 'D');
});

var newValues = allValues.splice(0, length).join();
alert(newValues);
```

Comment: its working. one change. deletedString should be sorted before splice

Comment: True. You can sort here or provide sorted data from server.

Comment: @VijayakumarS I changed the code in the answer to sort, but didn't test it.